# isomorphism $ \Bbb CG $ modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $ \Bbb CG$ algebra, and let $ x= \sum  _{g \in G} g $ . We define the module $ \Bbb Cx=\{cx: c \in C\}$. I must prove that $$ \Bbb C   \cong _{ \Bbb CG} \Bbb  Cx $$ Any ideas about that..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Find an isomorphism! The map $\Bbb C\to \Bbb C x$ is determined by where $1$ is sent. You can't really go wrong here: try anything nonzero and it'll work. Then just prove it's a $\Bbb C G$-module isomorphism.

Comment: thanks..that's what i am trying..to find the map..i have difficulties..

Comment: The definition of $\mathbb{C}x$ is telling you precisely where to send the complex number $c.$

Comment: @georgeson1960 "The" map? There's more than one available to work with. Like I said, you **don't even have to try - any nontrivial map will work**! Just do it!